# Upper to Lowercase conversion in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below columns in from 2 different tables -

```
DimTeamProject.ProjectNodeGUID             DimIteration.ProjectGUID 
------------------------------             ------------------------   
FAE8B08E-286E-487D-B1C1-011853028CDB       fae8b08e-286e-487d-b1c1-011853028cdb
```

I was trying a join operation while matching the case. It gave me an error like

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

The query I was trying was -

```
select 
   p.ProjectNodeName, i.IterationName
from 
   DimTeamProject p, DimIteration i
where 
   (p.ProjectNodeGUID) = UPPER(i.ProjectGUID)
```

I tried the "char" and "cast" function too but without success. Please help.

DimIteration.ProjectGUID is an "nvarchar" & DimTeamProject.ProjectNodeGUID is an "uniqueidentifer"

Comment: What are the data types of both columns?  I assume one is a varchar and the other is a uniqueidentifier?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just cast the appropriate side as a `uniqueidentifier`:

```
select p.ProjectNodeName, i.IterationName
from DimTeamProject p
inner join DimIteration i on p.ProjectNodeGUID = 
    CAST(i.ProjectGUID as uniqueidentifier)
```

See the demo with a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02f10/2).

Comment: Thanks. The below worked for me -select p.ProjectNodeName, i.IterationName
from DimTeamProject p
inner join DimIteration i on p.ProjectNodeGUID = 
    CAST(i.ProjectGUID as uniqueidentifier)